# How do we protect our Wordpress from hacker?

Tags: php, security, apache, wordpress, moveabletype

it's can be apply not only to wordpress. But to all blog platform that can be installed into a server and shared host. so, What do you do via PHP coding or pluggin or any method to secure your installation ?

Comment: I think this would be a ServerFault question.

Comment: off to serverfault for you. the single most important thing to do is to keep it up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limit access to ftp. For this, upload to server file **.ftpaccess**, and paste following code:

```
<Limit ALL>
Deny from all
Allow from Your.IP.Address
</Limit>
```

Also, limit access to most important files (like wp-login.php), uploading in the same folder file **.htaccess**:

```
<Files "wp-login.php">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from Your.IP.Address
</Files>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could modify the .htaccess file to deny permission to `/wp-admin*` if the IP address doesn't match yours.

Answer (score 1):

Being on a shared host is a bad limitation.  This prevents you from installing a web application firewall like Mod_Security.

[Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) is a list of steps you can take to harden your Wordpress installation.